# How to narrow the middle area with scale_color_gradient2() while preserving a midpoint

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can use scale_color_gradient2() to create a gradient fill in my density plot.
**I would like to narrow the white area in the middle.** For instance to allow the red and blue to reach full saturation at x-values of 0.5. How can I do this?

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- density(x, n = 2^12)
mydf <- data.frame(x = y$x, y = y$y)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + 
    geom_segment(
        aes(xend = x, yend = 0, color = x)
        ) + 
    scale_color_gradient2(
        low = "red", 
        mid = "white", 
        high = "blue", 
        midpoint = 0
      )
```

[image]

I can get pretty close to my desired result with scale_color_denistyn(), but then I lose my ability to specify a midpoint

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + 
    geom_segment(
        aes(xend = x, yend = 0, color = x)
        ) + 
    scale_color_gradientn(
        colors = c(rep("red", 5), "white", rep("blue", 5))
        # midpoint = 0
      )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `values` argument of `scale_color_gradientn` to precisely control where the colors change, along with `rescale`:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_segment(
    aes(xend = x, yend = 0, color = x)
  ) + 
  scale_color_gradientn(
    colors = c('red', 'red', 'white', 'blue', 'blue'),
    values = scales::rescale(c(min(mydf$x), -0.5, 0, 0.5, max(mydf$x)), 0:1)
  )
```

[image]